# PWA Firebase Push Notifications "This site has been updated in the background "

Tags: javascript, firebase, push-notification, progressive-web-apps

I have been testing push notifications for a PWA(Progressive-Web-App) through Firebase but everytime i Recieve the notification it just says "Chrome Push Notification: This site has been updated in the background". I  am testing it in localhost and tried testing similar answer but nothing seems to fix it.

[image: this is the notification I send]

And This is my serviceworker:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

// Update 'version' if you need to refresh the cache
var version = 'v1.0::CacheFirstSafe';
var offlineUrl = "Offline"; // <-- Offline/Index.cshtml
var urlsToCache = ['./', offlineUrl]; // <-- Add more URLs you would like to cache.

// Store core files in a cache (including a page to display when offline)
function updateStaticCache() {
    return caches.open(version)
        .then(function (cache) {
            return cache.addAll(urlsToCache);
        });
}

function addToCache(request, response) {
    if (!response.ok && response.type !== 'opaque')
        return;

    var copy = response.clone();
    caches.open(version)
        .then(function (cache) {
            cache.put(request, copy);
        });
}

function serveOfflineImage(request) {
    if (request.headers.get('Accept').indexOf('image') !== -1) {
        return new Response('<svg role="img" aria-labelledby="offline-title" viewBox="0 0 400 300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><title id="offline-title">Offline</title><g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"><path fill="#D8D8D8" d="M0 0h400v300H0z"/><text fill="#9B9B9B" font-family="Helvetica Neue,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif" font-size="72" font-weight="bold"><tspan x="93" y="172">offline</tspan></text></g></svg>', { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'image/svg+xml' } });
    }
}

self.addEventListener('install', function (event) {
    event.waitUntil(updateStaticCache());
});

self.addEventListener('activate', function (event) {
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.keys()
            .then(function (keys) {
                // Remove caches whose name is no longer valid
                return Promise.all(keys
                    .filter(function (key) {
                        return key.indexOf(version) !== 0;
                    })
                    .map(function (key) {
                        return caches.delete(key);
                    })
                );
            })
    );
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) {
    var request = event.request;

    // Always fetch non-GET requests from the network
    if (request.method !== 'GET' || request.url.match(/\/browserLink/ig)) {
        event.respondWith(
            fetch(request)
                .catch(function () {
                    return caches.match(offlineUrl);
                })
        );
        return;
    }

    // For HTML requests, try the network first, fall back to the cache, finally the offline page
    if (request.headers.get('Accept').indexOf('text/html') !== -1) {
        event.respondWith(
            fetch(request)
                .then(function (response) {
                    // Stash a copy of this page in the cache
                    addToCache(request, response);
                    return response;
                })
                .catch(function () {
                    return caches.match(request)
                        .then(function (response) {
                            return response || caches.match(offlineUrl);
                        });
                })
        );
        return;
    }

    // cache first for fingerprinted resources
    if (request.url.match(/(\?|&)v=/ig)) {
        event.respondWith(
            caches.match(request)
                .then(function (response) {
                    return response || fetch(request)
                        .then(function (response) {
                            addToCache(request, response);
                            return response || serveOfflineImage(request);
                        })
                        .catch(function () {
                            return serveOfflineImage(request);
                        });
                })
        );

        return;
    }

    // network first for non-fingerprinted resources
    event.respondWith(
        fetch(request)
            .then(function (response) {
                // Stash a copy of this page in the cache
                addToCache(request, response);
                return response;
            })
            .catch(function () {
                return caches.match(request)
                    .then(function (response) {
                        return response || serveOfflineImage(request);
                    })
                    .catch(function () {
                        return serveOfflineImage(request);
                    });
            })
    );
});

self.addEventListener('push', function (event) {
    console.log('Received a push message', event);

    var title = 'Yay a message.';
    var body = 'We have received a push message.';
    var icon = './Content/image/apple-icon-180x180.png';
    var tag = 'simple-push-demo-notification-tag';
    var data = {
        doge: {
            wow: 'such amaze notification data'
        }
    };

    event.waitUntil(
        self.registration.showNotification(title, {
            body: body,
            icon: icon,
            tag: tag,
            data: data
        })
    );
});


self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function (event) {

    // here data you access from event using event.notification.data
    console.log('On notification click: ', event.notification.tag);

});
```

})();